# Brunch Not Pulling in Bootstrap via bower.js

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bower, brunch

Brand new to Brunch (and kind of bower).  I installed Bootstrap via bower and I have the following brunch config file:

```
exports.config =
  # See http://brunch.io/#documentation for docs.
  files:
    javascripts:
      joinTo: 'app.js': /^(app|vendor|bower_components)/
      order:
        before: [
          'bower_components/jquery/jquery.js'
          'bower_components/handlebars/handlebars.js'
          'bower_components/ember/ember.js'
          'bower_components/ember-data-shim/ember-data.js'
          'bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js'
        ]
    stylesheets:
      joinTo: 'app.css': /^(app|vendor|bower_components)/
    templates:
      precompile: true
      root: 'templates'
      joinTo: 'app.js': /^app/
```

I'm not getting any of the bootstrap css into my `app.css`.  It is, however, showing the js in `app.js`.  Not real sure what might be wrong.

Comment: hey @Gregg did you eventually figure this out? I got the exact same [problem](https://github.com/scotch/angular-brunch-seed/issues/108)

Comment: I'm having this same problem, but the JS is not being included. Anyone figure this out?

Comment: @abbood a bit late, but see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is bower.json configuration in bower_components dependency folder.

e.g. Bootstrap as bower dependency doesn't export .css stylesheet, instead it uses Less. Unfortunately brunch will not compile .less files without less-brunch.

```
  "main": [
    "less/bootstrap.less",
    "dist/js/bootstrap.js"
  ]
```

### So, there are 2 solutions:

### 1.

Simply install less-brunch

```
npm install less-brunch --save
```

---

### 2.

Override dependency configuration in your main bower.json telling bower to export .css stylesheet.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "bootstrap": {
      "main": [
        "dist/css/bootstrap.css",
        "dist/js/bootstrap.js"
      ]
    }
  }
```

Now you should have all your dependencies imported in app.css

Remember to install css-brunch with

```
npm install css-brunch --save
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to tell brunch about it's bower dependencies via bower.json example:

```
{
  "name": "your-app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "www/app.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": ">=3.2.0"
  },
  "overrides": {}
}
```

Comment: Does this mean all bower dependencies have to be copied to package.sjon?

Comment: Yes then just run bower install from with the same folder as bower.json is located

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't answer @PumWalters's question - package.json is for items installed as node modules, using npm. This is different from bower.json, which is the manifest for items installed using bower.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while following the Brunch guide. The problem that I didn't have the [Brunch CSS plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-brunch) installed. Use *npm* to install *css-brunch*:

```
npm install css-brunch --save-dev
```